# Can't instantiate object on panel with proper alignment at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, panel, instantiation

I am trying to sprite renderers at runtime onto a panel, from left to right. I've tried setting the position both before and after setting the panel as the parent, and can't seem to get it to work. Either the object spawns in the middle of the panel, in the middle of the screen, or somewhere outside the screen. I think I'm just not understanding the change of base between coordinates or something.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class LoadPanel : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<GameObject> spriteRendererList = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject spritePanel;

    void Start () {
        Sprite[] spriteArray = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("sprites");
        Vector3 panelPos = spritePanel.transform.position;
        RectTransform panelRT = spritePanel.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        float panelWidth = panelRT.rect.width;

        for (int i = 0; i < spriteArray.Length;;  i++)
        {
             Vector3 panelItemPos = new Vector3(panelPos.x + i * 5, panelPos.y, 0);
             Instantiate(spriteRendererList[i], panelItemPos, Quaternion.identity);
             spriteRendererList[i].transform.SetParent(spritePanel.transform);
             spriteRendererList[i].transform.position = panelPos + new Vector3((panelPos.x-panelWidth)/2 + i*10,0,0);
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the `getWorldCorners()` function to determine the proper position and width/length of the panel. Still not sure why the previous approach didn't work, but `getWorldCorners` should fix this issue.